# How to pass command line argument when using source()

Tags: r

I am using r in windows using RGui(64-bit)
I use source command to execute a .r file.

```
 source('do_something.r')
```

**Have few questions:**

1. How can i pass arguments on command line ( in gui)

Example: I want to print value 10

do_something.r content:only below line
arg1

**Getting below error:**

```
> source('do_something.r') 10
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "source('do_something.r') 10"
```

How can i fix that? what should be correct syntax of passing the arguments? I searched around and nothing really clear(only thing i understood was the need to write functions etc...ouch i am not much a programmer, i am a DBA :) ). i am new to r.

2. I am finding it really boring to call "Source('do_something.r'" to call the script. Is there any better way to do that ( which doesnt involve playing to in windows control panel etc , i a command line guy :) )?

Comment: You can't pass parameters to source, `source("script.R")` simply executes in the current R session the code present in the script.R file, so you can do for example `x=10;source("scriptUsingVariableX.R")`. Anyway, if you like the command line, in window you can execute a script with `Rscript.exe script.R` and inside script.R you can get the command arguments using function `commandArgs()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no notion of a "command line" for the R parser. It executes a complete function call if it finds one in the "do_something.r" file before moving on to any expression that might follow the correct separator, a semi-colon. The parser will not pass the trailing expression to the evaluator until the sourced code is completed, so will not "see" any expression that follows. You have two choices:

To do this from the RGui console you need to do something like:

```
 val <- 10; source("do_something.r")  # set value first, then `source`
```

To use a "real" command line (not from the RGui), try this (assuming that the code in do_something.r will access a variable named `val`):

```
Rscript do_something.r -e 'val <- 10'
```

See `?Rscript` for more details and examples.